# Cisco Switch went mad

Tags: cisco, switch, connection, interface

tI have a Cisco SLM2048 Smart Switch which I can't access anymore. The switch is working just fine but:

- I can't reach it by web interface
- Doesn't seem to be able to reset it, even if I hold reset button for 10, 20, 30, 60 seconds.
- Doesn't get an ipv4 address, although I can ping it by an ipv6 address I discovered
- In wireshark, I can intercept Malformed\Erroneous packets sent by the switch

Problem is the thing doesn't have any console, so I'm really lost on how to try to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Disconnect all ports except the port you have your management machine connected to. It's possible that it's something silly, like portfast enabled or spanning tree disabled on a port that leads back to another port on the same switch indirectly.

Comment: These "Cisco" (Linksys) switches has caused us nothing but trouble. I recommend you look at more enterprise-grade hardware. We're happy after switching over to HP-2520 switches.

Comment: +1 for the antropomorphism :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My fix for a switch like that would be to replace it. If still under warranty send it back to Cisco, otherwise eat the loss and buy a new one.

Why?

- Clearly something is broken when you get malformed packets. That
  shouldn't happen. And you should be able to factory-reset the equipment.
- A switch which starts to act up can cause nightmarish network problems.
  Especially if you are running STP.
- The cost in time and effort of
  debugging a broken switch compared to the cost of replacement is bad
  on the cost-benefit scale in all but the most cash-limited
  organizations

Answer (score 0):

I heard that exactly same story from a friend of mine.

Send the switch back to Cisco (Linksys in this case).

Comment: This is exactly the same as the existing, accepted answer. Do you have something else to add?